# Namespace Windows.Devices.I2c nowhere to find

Tags: arduino, i2c, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

i am trying to communicate with i2c slaves on raspberry pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT Build 14393 (Background Application C#).
I cannot find the nemspace Windows.Devices.**I2c** anywhere. I have referenced Windows 10 Iot Extensions in different versions.

*Can anyone point me to why this is?*

[image: No namespace]

**UPDATE:**
Resolved. See answer (and vote please ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have older / multiple versions installed of Windows Software Developer Kit, there are issues with namespaces apparently.
Fix: Remove the old installations and/or make a repair of the current version of Windows Software Developer Kit.

Please refer to MSDN:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/101bdffa-d523-4f68-939d-64a037d58e6a/typeloadexception-on-windowsdevicesi2ci2cdevice?forum=WindowsIoT